# can't install any wp plugins

Tags: plugins, htaccess, rewrite-rules

We recently moved WP hosts.

We backed up WP and imported it to a development site wp.mysite.com to get it all set up.

Once everything was done, we switched the DNS and went live with newdomain.com on the new server. It's been running for a while but I now see a problem with plug-ins. The end user wanted to add a plugin but gets a 403 permissions denied error and at the top of the error it lists wp.mysite.com (the old development site URL). So as it stands we cannot add any plug-ins.

I downloaded the entire database in SQL text and searched but couldn't find any references to wp.mysite.com.

My assumption is that the permalink hash does not match the permalinks (which appear correct).

I've went to  Settings >> Permalinks and saved but they did not correct.
Could this be corrected with a RewriteRule in .htaccess where wp.mysite.com gets redirected to newsite.com?

Is there a better way to correct the permalink hash?

Comment: This is nearly a verbatim duplicate of [#405398](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/405398/how-to-fix-permalink-hash-that-doesnt-match-permalink) and may be closed for the same reasons. Additionally, two recommendations were made in the comments to that question that it's unclear if you ever attempted.

Comment: if you're having issues with installing plugins i don't see what that has to do with permalinks, but you should contact your host, hosting support issues are offtopic here and too localised. Likewise if you're having issues with Yoast and permalinks then you should contact their support. This stack is for development questions about WordPress itself, not 3rd party plugins or local server issues

Comment: I changed it slightly and reposted because people were hung up on Yoast plug-in and not that fact that *no* plug-ins will install. I assumed it was closed for being plug-in specific. 
In the yoast table there are "permalink" and "permalink hash" columns. 
Actually your comment just now has been the most helpful because it gave me some threads to pull. It may not be a permalink hash issue after all.